# Java - When a global variable is declared and initialized with a value, the what happens while object creation?

Tags: java, memory-management

When a global variable is declared and initialized with a value, then while creating object of the class, is the global variable again gets initialized and gets a new memory?

```
class A{

int a = 10;

}
```

This will gets stored in the memory address `a` with value `10`. But when I create object of the class A, then is the a gets initialized again?

```
class A{

int a = 10;

public static void main(String args[]){

A a = new A();

}
```

Comment: Java does not have global variables. Variables are not memory addresses.

Comment: @chrylis Java _does_ have global variables, and while variables are not memory addresses, they are something very similar, namely the storage _behind_ these memory addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you said is not quite how memory allocation works.

```
class A{

int a = 10;

}
```

in the above example you created a class. the members in the class are only created and assigned their values after their objects are created unless the the members are declared as static. hence the variable 'a' is assigned the value 10 after the construction of the object 'a' of class A in the second example you posted. If you still don't understand, then run this code:

```
class A{
int a = 10;
public static void main(String args[]){
A a = new A();
A b = new A();
b.a += 10;
System.out.println(a.a);
System.out.println(b.a);
}
}
```

if the variable a was assigned before creation of object, then when object b modifies it, the variable printed would change. But if you run this the out put will be:

```
10
20
```

which means that the variables only got assigned after object creation. I hope this clears your doubt. Also another tip for you, Static variables cannot be modified.

Comment: Thanks @EBIN for your answer! I understood that the part which happens after object creation. But when before that when there is only this line is present in the class int a =10. At this point what happens?

Comment: well class is a structure for an object. until the object is created, the memory will not be allocated. as for what happens to that 'int a = 10;' statement, that is encoded in to the class structure when the code is compiled to byte code.

Comment: the only way to allocate memory for a member variable before object creation is to make it static

Comment: Thanks a lot! This clarifies my question.

Answer (score 1):

> When a global variable is declared and initialized with a value...

What you have shown is not a *global variable*. Truly global variables do not exist in Java. `a` is an *instance field* of `A`.

> This will gets stored in the memory address a with value 10.

`a` is not a memory address, it is just the name of the field. You rarely need to deal with low-level stuff such as memory addresses in Java.

> But when I create object of the class A, then is the a gets initialized again?

Before you create an instance, no memory is allocated for the `a` field, except maybe for storing the compiled class file itself. It is once you create an instance of `A` that there is a place in memory storing the value `10` that corresponds to the `a` field of that instance.

Note that if you create a *second* instance of `A`, another piece of memory will be allocated to hold the `a` of that instance.

Comment: Well, a _different_ `a` will get initialized.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper for your answer! I understood a bit. But will need more clarification as in, at first when int a = 10; is written inside a class, that time what actually happens? Will it hold a memory or not.

Comment: It will happen when this line is run: `A a = new A();` The line itself will hold memory of course. The computer has to remember what code you has written after all. @Kaustubh

Comment: @chrylis Wording wasn't the best there, was it? Fixed.

Comment: @Sweeper: OK! So, at the moment I write A a = new A(), that time only a gets the memory? Correct me If I am still wrong.

Comment: @Kaustubh Note that it is ambiguous which `a` you are referring to. Both the local variable `a` (of type `A`) and the instance field `a.a` gets allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

There is no global variables in Java. There are class and object variables. Class variables are defined by the `static` keyword.

In your code, the `a` variable is an object variable, it is created (and initialized) every time a new object of the class is created, in this case, with the call `new A()`.

If you created another object of the class A, another object variable `a`would be created (and initialized) for it, different that the first one.